# Xamarin Android I need to kill a Foreground Service and a Notification when app has been closed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Let me explain the scenario.
I have a task I need to schedule in every 10 minutes.
This task needs both network and disk resources EVEN if the app is in the background AND even if the Battery Saver has kicked in.
I tried AlarmManager, JobScheduler, and ForegroundService.
Then only one that seems to work when Battery Saver kicks in is the ForegroundService.

In xamarin I have started a Foreground Service in the MainActivity.cs like the following.

```
void StartSomeService()
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SomeService));
    StartForegroundService(intent);
}
```

Inside my "foreground" service I have a Notification that is displayed in android.
I need to kill the foreground service when the application is closed by the user swiping it off the screen or hitting the "X".

This section DOES kill / close the notification but it does not feel right in that I am calling StartService again just to kill the service.

**TestService**

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    if ("stop_service" == intent.Action)
    {
        StopForeground(true);
        StopSelf();
    }
    else
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        RegisterForegroundService();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {                        
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

                // DO SOME WORK
            }
        });
    }

    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TestService));
    intent.SetAction("stop_service");
    StartService(intent);

    base.OnDestroy();
}
```

Comment: If you wanna detect when an app was removed from device RECENT list by swiping it away you can override the service's `OnTaskRemoved` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop a foreground service I usually use:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForegroundService));
StopService(intent);
```

This will in turn trigger `OnDestroy()` inside of the foreground service.

In `OnDestroy()` I then do:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
{
    StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
}
else
{
    StopForeground(true);
}

StopSelf();
```

Otherwise I have seen odd things with the service starting again, without it stopping itself.

Comment: does it not work   StopForeground(true); for all Sdk versions?

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had the same issue where I need my foreground service to end if the user swipes the app to close it.

What has worked for me is to override OnTaskRemoved which is called when the user removes a task that is involved in the service operation. You can put Cheesebaron's code inside of this method and it should stop the foreground service. I also added a line to terminate the app, otherwise it seems that the app continues to run in the background:

```
public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
            }
            else
            {
                StopForeground(true);
            }

            StopSelf();

            base.OnDestroy();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

        }
```

Comment: I can't afford to kill the current process if the user stops the foreground service, so is there another way to ensure it does actually stop the service when the user closes the app?

Comment: how can user do that " when the user removes a task that is involved in the service operation"? can you explain what you exactly mean?