# Finish foreground service thread

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a foreground service with a thread that is continuously checking data from a server.
So the service works well and it doesn't closes when I close the app, but when I start the app again the service creates another thread. Is posible abort the thread of the previous instance?

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static Activity ActivityCurrent { get; private set; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(0, 120, 71));
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Iniciado");
        LoadApplication(new App());
        ActivityCurrent = this;
        DependencyService.Get<IServicio>().Start();
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

This is my service class

```
[Service(ForegroundServiceType = Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeDataSync)]
public class Servicio : Service, IServicio
{

    Uri link = new Uri(new Url().Dir + "/estado_alarma.php");
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    Thread refrescar;
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int starId)
    {

        if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Se ha iniciado el servicio");
            RegisterNotification();
        }
        else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
        {
            StopForeground(true);
            StopSelfResult(starId);
        }
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;

    }

    private void RegisterNotification()
    {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServicioChannel", "Demo de servicio", NotificationImportance.Max);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServicioChannel").SetContentTitle("Servicio Trabajando").SetOngoing(true).Build();
        StartForeground(200, notification);

        _ = IniciarServicio();
    }
    public void Start()
    {

        Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(Servicio));
        startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
        MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(Servicio));
        startService.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
        MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
    }

    public int IniciarServicio()
    {
        refrescar = new Thread(EsperaAlarmaAsync);
        refrescar.Start();
        return 1;
    }
    public async void EsperaAlarmaAsync()
    {
        WebClient cliente = new WebClient();
        byte[] respuesta;
        string resultado;
        var a = true;
        while (a)
        {
            respuesta = cliente.DownloadData(link);
            resultado = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(respuesta);
            cliente.Dispose();
            if (resultado == "Alerta")
            {

                setNotificationVolumeToMax();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage = new Alerta();

                    var powerManager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(PowerService);
                    var wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.ScreenDim | WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup, "Ejemplo");
                    wakeLock.Acquire();
                    Intent x = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.Intent);
                    StartActivity(x);

                });
                a = false;
            }


            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
        refrescar.Abort();

    }
    private void setNotificationVolumeToMax()
    {
        try
        {
            var audioManager = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);

            int max_volume = audioManager.GetStreamMaxVolume(Android.Media.Stream.Music);
            audioManager.SetStreamVolume(Android.Media.Stream.Music, max_volume, 0);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

When the server return 'Alerta' it opens the app

Comment: We can't debug a story, you need to show minimally what you are doing for a reasonable answer

Comment: And no you never abort threads, you close them cooperatively

Comment: Please provide your code directly into your question and do not answer your question with additional informations about your question.

Comment: My guess is you'll run into permission issues trying to abort a thread that your new process doesn't own, although I've never worked in Android.  Have you checked if there is a way to signal to the OS to keep your app running in the background when it's minimized and signal the thread to stop when the app is actually shut down?  You could still deallocate all your resources on minimize and just keep the process alive so you still own the background thread.

Comment: What happens if you do the two lines of code in the first snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56643593/199364)? Do that BEFORE starting it again - see if it successfully locates the existing foreground service. If it does, you can either stop it, or maybe can continue using it. (Not sure.) I'm thinking it might, because you are running the same app again, hence same app id. If this works, please add what worked as "Your Answer" below. And give the same link I did, to acknowledge their contribution. So everyone will see that there is an answer to the question.